# Can a force field that absorbs kinetic energy protect someone from a nuclear bomb?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic

In my modern fantasy story, a nuclear bomb is launched and lands in a city 30 miles away from a wizard. He creates an airtight force field to protect himself. Would the force field protect him by absorbing the kinetic energy from the blast or would he be killed by the radiation?

Comment: How big is the blast? [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) would probably kill within 30 miles by light/heat/radiation.

Comment: It depends if the forcefield is transparent or opaque to visible light, gamma rays, neutrons ect. If it lets radioactive dust in. How long can the wizard keep up the forcefield, how big is the nuke? How bad is the fallout. Is there anything that might shelter the wizard? and many more questions.

Comment: Of course it depends on the size of the bomb, but with typical warheads in the 1 megaton range, your wizard wouldn't need any shielding at all. (Other than perhaps a really good pair of sunglasses :-)) There are various calculators for nuclear blast effects on the web.  This is the first one that showed up in Google: https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/

Comment: temperature soar to 300000degC near to the site, in short any unprotected human simply vaporized. Now you are asking for a airtight bubble to withstand heat up to 5.4x hotter than surface of Sun!

Comment: When using the [tag:magic] tag, remember to describe how your magic system works. As is, there are no constraints on how this "force field" operates and you are free to apply it in whatever way suits the needs of your story.

Comment: If magic is involved then almost anything is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get realistic. The nuclear weapon is launched, which it is delivered by a missile, and missile-delivered nuclear warheads will be typically a one-hundred kiloton bomb.

> > **Effects of a 100-kt nuclear bomb**
>
> - **3 km radius** A radioactive fireball hotter than the Sun and with the    force of 100,000 tonnes of TNT kills everyone.
> - **5 km radius** The vast majority of people die quickly from blast    injuries, asphyxiation or (over weeks) radiation sickness.
> - **10 km radius** About half die from trauma and burns. Many succumb soon    after to fires and radiation sickness.
> - **80 km radius** Radioactive fallout spreads. Over time, many thousands    will die from radiation sickness and cancers.

Source: [Blast, heat and radiation](http://www.icanw.org/the-facts/catastrophic-harm/blast-heat-and-radiation/)

The wizard is 30 miles (48 kilometres) from ground zero or the targeted city. A quick guesstimate from the above effects suggests the wizard will be safe from the blast effects. So he doesn't need a kinetic energy absorbing force-field from protection. He might need a force-field to absorb radiant energy, act as a fire shield, and keep out radioactive fallout.

Assuming the nuclear weapon is a typical missile warhead, then the wizard should be reasonably safe from the immediate effects of its detonation. However, a kinetic absorbing force-field won't be of much protection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could, if the kinetic energy absorbing affected particles down to wavelengths of light. What radiation released from a nuclear is is non-visible (to humans) electromagnetic radiation. By absorbing the kinetic energy, and therefore lengthening the wavelength of electromagnetic radiation, turning it into harmless visible light and then light with a even longer wavelength than radio waves, it would dissipate into harmless electromagnetic radiation waves. (I know I'm saying electromagnetic radiation a lot, but it's not exactly light and not exactly radiation in the common use of the word) The drawback to this is it would also diffuse visible light, meaning the said wizard could not see anything beyond the force field's influence. Also, the force field would appear to be a perfectly black (shape of force field) from the outside as well.

The heat would be handled in the same way, because heat is simply atoms and molecules jiggling faster or slower, the shield would then slow down the gyration of the atoms to the point where the heat wave would no longer affect objects inside the force field. This would create a super cooled area directly surrounding the force field, as the molecules would reach absolute zero, depending on how affective the force field is. Anything that touched with the outside of the force field would likely shatter as its temperature dropped rapidly.

Thirdly, any shockwaves power would be absorbed by the kinetic energy nullifying powers of the forcefield. This would also leave the area directly behind the force field (relative to the center of the blast) in a 'wind shadow' and not as affected by the shockwave.

Finally, in order to survive the now radioactive wasteland he stands in, the wizard would have to keep the force field sustained until he exited the area of radiation.

Comment: Why do you think visible light is harmless?  Take an ordinary magnifying glass outside on a sunny day, and you can start fires with that "harmless" visible light.  The effect scales up quite usefully, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odeillo_solar_furnace

Comment: I meant harmless, relative to uv, gamma, and other higher wavelength radiation.

Comment: But those are also harmless at low intensity.  UV's even necessary for vitamin D production.  It's the intensity that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about 30 miles distance then we are mostly talking about thermal effects. At this distance there is about 50 tons of air per m2 between bomb and target so radiation is weakened. I don't know how good his shield is, but for very powerful bombs flash effect stays dangerous further than blast wave's even for unprotected targets.

And this bomb would have to be very powerful to be able to hurt a man at that distance. A [1-megaton explosion](http://www.atomicarchive.com/Effects/effects13.shtml) can cause flash blindness at distances as great as 13 miles on a clear day, or 53 miles on a clear night. Blindness would pass in some minutes - so effects would be rather minor. [Tsar bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) could have caused third-degree burns 100 km (62 mi) away from ground zero, that would be hard to recover from even with magic.

Comment: You mean "fourth degree burns"?

Comment: @Alexander thx, fixed